# android store image from gallery to database

Tags: android, database, image, gallery

i want to make a database that stores images from the users gallery the images are in the form of bitmaps. i already have a simple database that stores texts like names, i was wondering if you know a way i could just simply add the image into my already existing database.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        Button pic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        pic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ImageView picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        picture.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, recipelayout.class);
        intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", picturePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

First, **convert your image into a byte array:**

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
 byte data = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

And then **write it to DB as a blob:**

```
SQLiteProgram prog = sqlite.compileStatement("insert into ...... values(?, ?)");
p.bindBlob(1, data);
p.execute();
```

The above method is possible but, from my own experience, inferior performance-wise to simply writing
your image to internal memory and saving its path in database:

**A.** Write the image to app's internal memory

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File directory = cw.getDir("MyInternalDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File mypath = new File(directory, "fileName.jpg");


Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath); //<----- or from any other source...

FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
    bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String filePath = directory.getAbsolutePath();
```

**B.** And store the filePath as a reference in DB

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put("ImagePath", filePath); 
database.insert(....);
```

I prefer the latter method. Feel free to choose your own.

Comment: what do i replace bitmapimage with

Comment: what do i replace "bitmapimage" with ?

Comment: bitmapimage is the produc of BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath) in your own code. See my changes in orig post.

Comment: what do i put in here for the image "public boolean insertContact  (String name, String phone")